# YouTube PlaylistItems API causing syntax errors when using JSON.parse()

Tags: node.js, json, youtube-api

I have 2 calls to the YouTube v3 API in my NodeJS code: [channels](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) and [PlaylistItems](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list). They both return JSON and the response to the first call is parsed just fine, but parsing the response to the second call causes a syntax error. I am uncertain whether it's an error on my side or in the PlaylistItems API endpoint.

Here is my code (taken out irrelevant parts):

```
// At start of the bot, fetches the latest video which is compared to if an announcement needs to be sent
function setLatestVideo () {
    fetchData().then((videoInfo) => {
        if (videoInfo.error) return;

        latestVideo = videoInfo.items[0].snippet.resourceId.videoId;
    });
}

// Fetches data required to check if there is a new video release
async function fetchData () {
    let path = `channels?part=contentDetails&id=${config.youtube.channel}&key=${config.youtube.APIkey}`;
    const channelContent = await callAPI(path);

    path = `playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=1&playlistId=${channelContent.items[0].contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads}&key=${config.youtube.APIkey}`;
    const videoInfo = await callAPI(path);

    return videoInfo;
}

// Template HTTPS get function that interacts with the YouTube API, wrapped in a Promise
function callAPI (path) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

        const options = {
            host: 'www.googleapis.com',
            path: `/youtube/v3/${path}`
        };

        https.get(options, (res) => {
            if (res.statusCode !== 200) return;

            const rawData = [];
            res.on('data', (chunk) => rawData.push(chunk));
            res.on('end', () => {
                try {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(rawData));
                } catch (error) { console.error(`An error occurred parsing the YouTube API response to JSON, ${error}`); }
            });

        }).on('error', (error) => console.error(`Error occurred while polling YouTube API, ${error}`));
    });
}
```

Examples of errors I'm getting: [Unexpected token , in JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsEmv.png) and [Unexpected number in JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq6TM.png)

Till ~2 weeks ago this code used to work just fine without throwing any errors, I have no clue what has changed and can't seem to figure it out. What could possibly be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

10 minutes later I figure out the fix! The variable `rawData` holds a `Buffer` and looking more into that, I figured that I should probably use `Buffer.concat()` on `rawData` before calling `JSON.parse()` on it. Turns out, that's exactly what was needed.

I'm still unsure how this was causing problems only 6 months after writing this code, but that tends to happen.

Changed code:

```
res.on('end', () => {
                try {
                    resolve(JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(rawData)));
                } catch (error) { console.error(`An error occurred parsing the YouTube API response to JSON, ${error}`); }
            });
```